# PowerMock Unexpected Method Call

Tags: java, junit, easymock, powermock

today I use PowerMock.expectNew to Mock a contrustor,I can pass all the code ,But when excute `PowerMock.verfy(classss.class)` a mistake will occured. The trace is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call InvocationSubstitute.performSubstitutionLogic(EasyMock for class com.tibco.sap.adapter.SAPApplication, "operationClassName"):
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at $Proxy8.performSubstitutionLogic(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.NewInvocationControlImpl.expectSubstitutionLogic(NewInvocationControlImpl.java:74)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.NewInvocationControlImpl.expectSubstitutionLogic(NewInvocationControlImpl.java:28)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doExpectNew(PowerMock.java:1845)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.expectNew(PowerMock.java:1856)
    at com.tibco.sap.mytest.SAPReqRespInvocImplTest.testSAPReqRespInvocImpl(SAPReqRespInvocImplTest.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

Comment: I think the key bits of code will be necessary to help here.

Comment: What is this line? com.tibco.sap.mytest.SAPReqRespInvocImplTest.testSAPReqRespInvocImpl(SAPReqRespInvocImplTest.java:69)

Comment: this line is PowerMock.expectNew(R3RFCMarshaller.class, app,"classRef").andReturn(marshaller);

Comment: I met this mistake when excutethe verfy scentance.

Comment: Hmm, could the mocking be in the wrong state when this is called?  I've only used PowerMockito.  Another possibility is an incompatibility in versions between PowerMock and EasyMock.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply so late,I replace the PowerMock to PowerMockito and solve the problem.Thank you,ash.

Comment: Oh, good to hear.  You're welcome!